# Showing that a Borel Measure $\mu\equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Problem.** Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $[0,1]$. Assume that
>
> 1. $\mu$ and Lebesgue measure $m$ are mutually singular.
> 2. $\mu([0,t])$ depends continuously on $t$.
> 3. $f\in L^{1}(\mu)$ for any function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $f\in L^{1}(m)$. (Note that $f$ has a finite value at every point.)
>
> Show that $\mu\equiv 0$.

This question was [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291876/how-to-prove-that-mu-0) before, but it did not receive a full answer--just a commented suggestion on how to proceed.

My issue is that I don't see why $\mu=\delta_{0}$ (i.e. the Dirac mass at $x=0$) is not a counterexample to the problem statement. $\delta_{0}$ and Lebesgue measure are mutually singular. $\mu([0,t])\equiv 1$, which is trivially continuous. And for any function $f$ satisfying 3. $\int f\mathrm{d}\mu=f(0)$, which is finite by hypothesis. Am I missing something obvious?

I believe I can show that under the hypotheses of the problem, we must have $\mu(\left\{0\right\})=\mu([0,1])$. Indeed, suppose that $\mu(\left\{0\right\})<\mu([0,1])$. Since $\mu$ and $m$ are mutually singular, there exist disjoint measure sets $A,B$ with $A\cup B=[0,1]$, $m(A)=0$, and $\mu(B)=0$. Since $F(t):=\mu([0,t])$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem (IVT) applies. By repeated application of IVT, we can inductively find an increasing sequence $\left\{t_{n}\right\}$ with

$$t_{0}:=0, \quad \alpha_{n+1}:=\mu([0,t_{n+1}])>\alpha_{n}:=\mu([0,t_{n}])$$
Note that it follows from the continuity of $F$ that $\mu(\left\{t\right\})=0$ for any $0<t\leq 1$. In particular, $\mu([t_{n},t_{n+1}))=\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_{n}$.

Now define a Borel measurable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by

$$f(s):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_{n}}\chi_{A\cap [t_{n},t_{n+1})}(s)$$

$f\in L^{1}(m)$, since $m(A)=0$, so $f\in L^{1}(\mu)$ by problem assumption. But then for any positive integer $N$,

$$\int f(s)\mathrm{d}\mu(s)\geq\sum_{n=0}^{N}\dfrac{1}{\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_{n}}\mu(A\cap [t_{n},t_{n+1}))=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\dfrac{1}{\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_{n}}\mu([t_{n},t_{n+1}))=\sum_{n=0}^{N}1=N$$

Whence, we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: I haven't read through the proof you gave. But you're absolutely right, the problem as stated is wrong, and yes a measure satisfies those conditions if and only if $\mu([0,1])=\mu(\{0\})$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: What was the proof you had in mind for arriving at the conclusion?

Comment: posted comment in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, a comment too long for the comment box:

Oh that's you - diidn't notice the name. Didja notice someone posted a proof for that Fourier series thing? Heh.

Don't know why you ask, when I said I hadn't read your proof I didn't mean to suggest I doubted it. Didn't have an actual proof in mind, seemed obvious...

Hmm. Ok, first the continuity makes it clear that $\mu(\{t\})=0$ for all $t\ne 0$. Say $d\nu=\chi_{(0,1]}\,d\mu$. Then we want to show $\nu=0$, and we know that $\nu$ vanishes on singletons. Say $\nu([0,1])=1$. Say $\nu$ is concentrated on $E$, $m(E)=0$.

Continuity shows that there exists a sequence $t_0<t_1\dots$ with $\nu([0,t_0])=1/2$ and $\nu((t_n,t_{n+1}])=2^{-(n+2)}$. Let $$E_n=E\cap(t_n,t_{n+1}]$$and set $$f=\sum 3^n\chi_{E_n}$$Then $f\notin L^1(\nu)$, although $f=0$ a.e.[$m$].

Comment: My apologies if it read like I was insinuated your doubt; that was not my intention. I asked because I was curious if the conclusion followed readily from a "bigger" theorem which I was forgetting. In the linked question, David Girade commented that the Lebesgue decomposition might be useful, but I don't see where that really helps. Regarding the Fourier series problem, I saw your answer--I even upvoted it! It looks very good, I'm just mulling it over. I am a bit surprised as I thought a solution would follow from the $N^{2}/k$ bound with an "orthogonality trick."

Comment: @MattRosenzweig About the Fourier series thing, I have the same questions.

Comment: @MattRosenzweig About this thing: What I posted was just spur of the moment. The more I think about it the more it seems like it's actually a _little_ theorem. All we need is this: If $\nu$ is a nonatomic probability measure on $X$ then there exists $f:X\to[0,\infty)$ with $\int f\,d\nu=\infty$. And hence all we need is that there exists a sequence of disjoint sets of positive measure. Which I got above in a very careful way. But it's obvious. Partition $X=E_1\cup F_1$ where both have positive measure. Partition $F_1=E_2\cup F_2$ where both have positive measure. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mu = \delta_0$. Then we have for the set $A = (0,1]$ and $B= \{0\}$ that $\mu(A) =0$ and $m(B)=0$ while $A \cup B = [0,1]$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. So we have property 1.

For property 2 we have $\mu ( [0,t])=1$ for all $0 \le t \le 1$, so clearly $\mu( [0,t])$ is continuous in $t$, thus also property 2 holds.

For the last property, for any $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(0) \in \mathbb{R}$, so $\int f \textrm{d} \mu = f(0) < \infty$, thus $f \in L^1(\mu)$.

So $\delta_0$ does satisfy all properties, and therefore is a valid counterexample.

Comment: Isn't this essentially what I wrote in my question statement?

Comment: Yes, so in short, you did not miss anything obvious.